# import with rollupjs, es2015 modules

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2, rollupjs

I'm using `rollupjs` as part of the new `ionic2@RC.0` release. The project is using `tsconfig.json` with `compilerOptions.module = "es2015"` instead of `"commonjs"` and it's totally new to me.

```
// typescript
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
```

I'm getting this `import` error from rollup

```
[17:40:45]  typescript compiler finished in 8.08 s
[17:40:45]  bundle dev started ...
[17:40:55]  Error: Module .../node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/index.js does not export AgmCoreModule (imported by .../.tmp/shared/shared.module.js)
    at Module.trace (.../node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:7677:29)
    at ModuleScope.findDeclaration 
    ...
```

the import file looks like this

```
// index.d.ts
/**
 * angular2-google-maps - Angular 2 components for Google Maps
 * @version v0.14.0
 * @link https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps#readme
 * @license MIT
 */
export * from './directives';
export * from './services';
export * from './map-types';
export { LatLngBounds, LatLng, LatLngLiteral, MapTypeStyle } from './services/google-maps-types';
export * from './core-module';


// index.js
/**
 * angular2-google-maps - Angular 2 components for Google Maps
 * @version v0.14.0
 * @link https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps#readme
 * @license MIT
 */
"use strict";
function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
// main modules
__export(require('./directives'));
__export(require('./services'));
// Google Maps types
// core module
__export(require('./core-module'));

//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

I can change my import to

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core/core-modules';
```

and `rollup` does not complain, but then `angular2` doesn't find the directives that were imported from `angular2-google-maps/core`

what should I do?

Comment: How are you importing the directives? Simply adding "AgmCoreModule.forRoot()" to imports[] in the NgModule annotation works for me (I also need to import 'angular2-google-maps/core/core-modules' tho)

Comment: that's what I did, but I had to add `imports[AgmCoreModule.forRoot()]` for both the `shared.modules.ts` and `app.modules.ts`

Comment: Yes, of course. It's in the getting started of angular2-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

When the `export * from ...` declarations in `angular2-google-maps/core/index.ts` gets compiled to JS using the `__export` function, Rollup loses it's ability to track what bindings are exported. If you instead use the ES6 version of the library available in the `esm/` (ECMAScript modules) directory everything should work.

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/esm/core/index.js';
```

Comment: I still get these errors `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2-google-maps/esm/core/index.js'.` or `error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../node_nodules/angular2-google-maps/esm/core/index.js'.`

TS did not complain about this: `import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core/core-modules';`

Answer (score 0):

For the Release Candidate, Ionic 2 moved from a gulp-based build process to one that now uses rollup.js for bundling. Most of the time third-party libraries "just work" - however in some cases (depending on how the library exported its components), you need to explicitly tell rollup.js what is being exported. This is what is happening here with Angular 2 Google Maps.

This is documented in the "Building" section of the Ionic 2 [App Build Scripts](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/app-scripts/) documentation page. **In short, you need to create a custom rollup.config.js file for your project to tell Rollup about `AgmCoreModule`**.

Here is a [blog post](http://stevemichelotti.com/integrate-angular-2-google-maps-into-ionic-2/) which fully documents the exact steps. Also, here is a [Github repo](https://github.com/smichelotti/ionic2-google-maps-test) which shows the fully functioning code.